# How to resolve Excel.Application.Workbooks.Open failing when called from WCF Service?

Tags: c#, .net, excel, wcf

I was wondering if you had a couple of minutes to read over a WCF issue I've been  working on trying to resolve.

I have a WCF service which utilizes XL Spreadsheets on the backend as part of it's calculation engine. I'm using a 3rd party  .Net based component called Aspose to access, manipulate and retrieve data from the spreadsheet.

Unfortunately, Aspose ran into a couple of calculation bugs. In in order to overcome these issues,  as a temporary fix, I save a temporary copy of the current spreadsheet. I then open the spreadsheet (which forces a recalc) with the Microsoft Excel .Net library - Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel. Then I reopen that temp spreadsheet using Aspose to collect  the result values

This fix has worked fine as I've been implementing/debugging the solution locally.

When I deployed the service to IS 7.0, the MS .Net Excel library fails when attempting to open the file.

I think this some kind of permissions issue with the deployed IIS service.

**This is a snippet of the code that is failing**

```
String fullPath1 = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "App_Data", "BCBSDiabetesCalculator.xlsm");

// Open to force Excel to perform calculation itself
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application excelApp1 = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();

var excelWorkbook1 = excelApp1.Workbooks.Open(fullPath1);
```

**The following code block where I opening a filestream and passing it to the Aspose library call works.**

```
//Get the Excel file into stream
FileStream stream = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open);

//Instantiate LoadOptions specified by the LoadFormat.
LoadOptions loadOptions = new LoadOptions(LoadFormat.Xlsx);

//Create a Workbook object and opening the file from the stream
_workbook = new Workbook(stream, loadOptions);

if (_workbook == null)
{
}

// Make sure that we close the stream.
stream.Close();
```

Do you have any insight/ideas on how to resolve this?

Comment: is excel installed on the server?

Comment: It is a horrible idea to use Office Interop from ASP.NET or another server technology. These APIs were written for use in a desktop application, for automating Office (a suite of desktop applications). Server applications are different in many ways that make it a very, very bad idea to use Office Interop in them. It's also unsupported by Microsoft, and may violate your Office license. See [Considerations for server-side Automation of Office](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257757)

Answer (score 1):

When you use Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel to open a file, this assumes Office is installed on the system spawning the process.   But, the interop dll will spawn a separate Excel process which you can identify using the Task Manager.  This Excel process is the actual desktop software being run in the background (it can be coded to run in the forground as well).  So if you do have Excel installed on the server, spawning a separate process from within IIS is most likely the culprit.  That being said, doing this should be avoided.  Running Office automation on servers is a fragile solution at best, as errors with the Excel process could lead to zombie processes or worse.  Microsoft advocates against this.

If possible, ( this is a suggestion since I have not used ASpose), use [OpenXML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb448854.aspx).  If you save the excel file to this format and ASpose can open it, you will not spawn an Excel process instance.  If you have to do server side work with Office, and you can use OpenXML, it will avoid having to run the desktop applications through the interop dlls and save you lots of headaches.